# How to pull from(14 or 1026) into or something other than(14 or 1026) included in report?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas

I used below criteria but result is not expected. I was trying to pull the rows from 2021-01-01 to 2021-12-31 date range but the code is not satisfied in the result. I was expecting to get the both rows  to the output result.

```
From t1 a
    ,t2 b
Where
A.id=b.id
And b.begDate <='2021-12-31'
And b.code in(14,1026)
And Exists (select 1 from t2 as b1
        Where
        a.id=b1.id
        And b1.enddate=b.begdate-1 day
        And b1.code not in(14,1026)
```

Input

```
-----id---begdate-----enddate------code--
      1.  2021-01-01. 2021-12-17.  1026
      2.  2021-12-18. 2021-12-31.  1026
```

Output: The same input rows I expecting to the output report

Comment: This `b.begdate-1 day `doesn't look like T-SQL to me? Is it SAS specific?

Comment: You will need to provide a much clearer description of what your query is attempting to accomplish. Include table schemas and relationships along with enough test data to demonstrate what works and what doesn't. Identify the differences between expected and actual results and describe why you believe the actual results are wrong. There's not much we can work with at this point.

Comment: I will say this, assuming that the 'Id' values are unique in table B, the query will never return any results as written. You have `A.id=b.id` and `a.id=b1.id`, which implies `b.id=b1.id`. You also have conditions `b.code in(14,1026)` and `b1.code not in(14,1026)`, which implies `b.code <> b1.code`. Both cannot be true if `b.id=b1.id` implies that the records are the same.  Also, your test data has different IDs, would not satisfy the indirect b.id=b1.id condition.

Comment: Please suggest me for this solution what needs to be done?

Comment: Evolve! No one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Again... "You will need to provide a much clearer description of what your query is attempting to accomplish." See above. (No one here except you has any idea what t1 is or what t2 or what you are trying to do with two t2 records. Explain what the Exists() is intended to test for.

Answer (score 0):

First issue for me is that you deal with character values like if they were dates. This is a bad practice to do that.

When you write `b.begDate <='2021-12-31'`, you compare variable `begDate` (which I assume is a date) versus a string.

In this case, it's an alphabetical sort that is used, which can work, but that's really not logic to do like this

If you want to hardcode a date, you can use the `d` indicator like this:
`b.begDate <='2021-12-31'd`

Then, I agree with T N, you have contradictory clauses in your code, that's why you output nothing. In particular, this clause excludes all the input records:

```
And Exists (select 1 from t2 as b1
        Where
        a.id=b1.id
        And b1.enddate=b.begdate-1 day
        And b1.code NOT in (14,1026)
```